# iOS web view error

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to play a Youtube video in my app with the Webview 
the build is succsesful but when i run the app it shows all white and i get this error: Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)
it happenes on the Youtube.loadRequest(URLRequest(url:url!))

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  CFBC
//
//  Created by KWIA on 6/6/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 KWIA. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Youtube: UIWebView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

getVideo(videoCode: "RmHqOSrkZnk")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func getVideo(videoCode:String)
    {
        let url = URL(string: "https//www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoCode)")
        Youtube.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is not valid, you are missing `:` after `https`.

It should be: `"https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoCode)"`

That leads to `URL(string:)` returning `nil` and to a crash when you try to force unwrap it using `!`.

Comment: @TheHypixelExoKnights What do you mean by "didnt work"? Is it still crashing on the same line?

Comment: @TheHypixelExoKnights I have just tried it. `let videoCode = "RmHqOSrkZnk";
let url = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoCode)")!` does not trigger any error.

Comment: put it all on one line?

Comment: @TheHypixelExoKnights Nope, that has nothing to do with it. The code with added `:` just works correctly.

Comment: @TheHypixelExoKnights Youtube videos are not supported in the simulator.